# Sticky Footer sort of working

Tags: css, sticky-footer

Got the sticky footer working on my site here is the CSS code

```
html, body {height:100%; }

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto; padding-bottom: 180px; }  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
margin-top: -180px; /* negative value of footer height */
min-height: 180px;
clear:both;}
```

But there is a white gap between body (where I have a bgcolour) and footer...tried everything, anyone had any similar issues?

Comment: We need your html and css, jsfiddle would be great. Do you use reset css in your project?

Answer (score 0):

You can user this css code to stick your footer at bottom

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    min-height: 180px;
}
```

So it will always stick at bottom.